# how to link Discussion Board with Custom list in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a custom list, which  have collection of goals. and i have an discussion board for discussions about those goals from that custom list... so how can i link between those two. what my expectation is, if I select a "goal" from custom list, then the collection of discussions that related to goals will displays on other side...  and i have added a lookup column in discussion board that refer the goal name in the custom list so i am relating goal name between these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to create 2 web parts (list and discussions) and connect them using the common value they have.